# How would I have a from print out HTML?

Tags: forms

I am building out a form to make it easier for our content people to make tabbed areas, and want the ability to have the output be html, instead of just text. I am using standard post method, but they will be putting image hrefs, and so forth in, and I need them to be able to copy the output and paste it into a page. I know this is simple, but.,..

Comment: Is this a .NET Windows Forms program or something else?

Comment: No, just plain old PHP. The way I have it now, it prints out the data, but they have to view source to get the raw html code that they can put into the page.

Answer (score 0):

I'm having trouble imagining the overall structure of what you're doing, but if you are looking for something really basic, you could use Javascript to copy the HTML from some element into a textarea:

```
<html>
<head>
<title></title>
<script type="text/javascript">
function showMarkup() {
    var src = document.getElementById("yourMarkupInHere");
    var target = document.getElementById("theMarkup");
    target.value = src.innerHTML;
    return false;
}
</script>
</head>
<body>
    <div id="yourMarkupInHere">
        <label for="username">User name:</label>
        <input id="username" type="text" />
    </div>
    <input id="bnShowMarkup" type="button" value="Show markup" onclick="showMarkup()" />
    <input id="theMarkup" type="textarea" readonly="readonly" />
</body>
</html>
```

It could really do with a larger textarea and some attempt at formatting the raw HTML.